# After Tomcat restart on VM, Youtrack resets

Tags: tomcat, vmware, youtrack

I've installed Tomcat today on my local VMware Workstation and loaded *.war YouTrack there. Everything was great until I needed to stop VM and reboot my PC. After that I started my VM again, went to address where YouTrack is based and it took me to "setUp" page immediately. What might be the reason for that? Am I loading it incorrectly? Why did it reset and began everything from the start?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS do you use? How do you Start Tomcat?

Most likely after restart Tomcat is running from the system service or different user account and therefore is using the blank database (since database is specific to the user account).

You need to ensure that Tomcat is always running from the same user account and there are read/write permissions for the directory where YouTrack stores its data.

Comment: On my `VMware Workstation` I installed `Ubuntu Server 10.04` and upon that I installed Tomcat. If I start Tomcat manually then there is no such problem, but if I'll use script for `autostart`, then there is exactly that problem.

Comment: autostart may use different user account or environment having another home directory.

Comment: No, you just need to change the configuration, environment, startup script or files location so that YouTrack loads its data from the same location or Tomcat always starts up with the same environment and user account. You can find details here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TSYSD/Adminitrator's+Guide#Adminitrator%27sGuide-ChangingDatabaseLocation. Use some fixed path instead of `${user.home}` and ensure that file system permissions are correct via chmod/chown.

Comment: Great I think, that setting up static ${user.home} made the trick.